# Ionic Cordova - Break out of QR code reader without scanning

Tags: ionic-framework, qr-code

Is it possible to escape from the QR code reader scan screen if called by mistake and there is no QR code to scan, currently it just keeps the camera open.

Comment: What scanning plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout to give some time to scan Qr if there is no scan handle that to exit camera or qr scanner

```
let TIME_IN_MS = 5000;

let closeCamera= setTimeout( () => {

 // somecode to handle scann Qr
}, TIME_IN_MS);
```